# replace startActivityForResult with startActivity + ResultReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Im using an external library that provides an authentication routine which is started with `startActivityForResult`. Right now, in order to get the result I've created an Activity that does nothing else than receiving the result and  passing it back to my module which integrates the lib:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    externalApiClient.onResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent, this);
}
```

I was thinking of making this activity invisible or size (1,1). But this doesn't feel right. So my question is: can I replace `startActivityForResult` with `startActivity` and pass it a `ResultReceiver`?

Comment: How is the `Activity` passing the result back to your module? Is that module an `Activity` or somthing else?

Comment: the module is just a plain java class - no activity. however i had to create an artificial activity to be able to receive the result where i would rather like to have just a callback

Comment: Yeah, well, the `Activity` you are calling via `startActivityForResult()` expects to return the result to an `Activity`, so you are kinda stuck there.  Obviously if you could modify the external library, you could provide an alternative callback mechanism (broadcast Intent, etc.), but otherwise you are stuck with the mechanism you've got. Sorry.